# How to remove alphabets and special characters from a string using REGEX in Windows Batch Script?

Tags: regex, batch-file

I need to remove letters a to z , A to Z and special characters. I only need digits and decimal point. I found a lot of examples using string manipulations but I think it is better to use regular expressions.

For example,

numbers = `10.20af24`

numbers must be equal to `10.20` and not `10.20af24`.

Thank you.

Comment: What you're describing here may not require it, but you can get more regex functionality out of PowerShell than the command line: http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html

Comment: That looks like hex. Have you tried `(?:[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])+` which would also match like 20 too, makes it hard unless you adhere to a strict format.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "num=10.20af24"
FOR /l %%d IN (1,1,999) DO SET result=!num:~0,%%d!&ECHO(!num:~%%d,1%!|FINDSTR /r "[0-9\.]" >nul&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO done
:done
ECHO %result%

GOTO :EOF
```

...since you insist on using a regex

Answer (score 0):

This helper batch file called `repl.bat` has regexp capability akin to SED `repl /?` for help - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

This helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` is akin to GREP - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

This works with your sample, but it's simplistic in this case:

```
@echo off
echo 10.20af24|repl "[a-zA-Z].*" ""
pause
```

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

Answer (score 0):

One more

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "string=10.20af24"
    set "num="
    for /f %%a in ('cmd /q /u /c "echo(%string%"^|more^|findstr /r /c:"[0-9.]"') do set "num=!num!%%a"

    echo %num%
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to use regular expressions, though Batch doesn't have any built in functionality for this. You could do something like the following -

```
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set number=!number:%%a=!
```

Example -

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set number=10.20af24
for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set number=!number:%%a=!
echo !number!
```

You can add other special characters into the for loop, but keep in mind that you may need to escape them with a carat `^`.